# How to create a function that receives a list of date parameters?

Tags: python, function, date, parameters

I am developing a function that creates columns with multiple dismemberments from the date field, such as: Day of week, week of month, year and month and others.

I need to create a function that the user can choose which columns he wants in the parameter, what I have developed now is:

```
for d in date_fields:
    data[d]=pd.to_datetime(data[d])
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_year']=data.loc[data[d].notnull(),d].dt.year.astype(str)
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_month']=data.loc[data[d].notnull(),d].dt.month.map("{:02}".format)
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_day']=data.loc[data[d].notnull(),d].dt.day.map("{:02}".format)
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_yearmonth']= data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_year']+data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_month']
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_week_of_month']=data.loc[data[d].notnull(),d].apply(lambda x : str(week_of_month(x)))
# Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_weekday']=data.loc[data[d].notnull(),d].dt.weekday.astype(str)
return data
```

How could I do the function that gets a list of parameters?

Comment: What part of making such a function do you need help with?

Comment: I am having difficulty creating the conditions that will be performed by the function. For example if the user only wants the year and month column. How to ensure that it will not generate all other date columns? Thanks Scott ;)

Comment: How is the user expected to indicate what she wants?  Can you provide an example, and what the result would be for that input?

Comment: The user chooses for example, day of the week and year month. Thus the function should take these two parameters as a list and create only these two columns.

My code generates all columns with date information, but this information is not always required. The possibilities are: year, month, day, yerarmonth, week of month and week day.

Comment: How does user communicate this choice?  What (an *example*, not a description) would the function return for that choice?

Comment: The user informs the parameters in the function that must be executed. -- def functionxyz(date, year, month): and the function executes only part of the code  --  for d in date_fields:
    data[d]=pd.to_datetime(data[d])
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_year']=data.loc[data[d].notnull(),d].dt.year.astype(str)
    data.loc[data[d].notnull(),f'{d}_month']=data.loc[data[d].notnull(),d].dt.month.map("{:02}".format).

Comment: Maybe I haven't thought of the best option for this case yet ;(